# Is there a sort of wildcards in nftables?

Tags: nftables

In iptables it was possible to use `eth+` as interface name to match any interface starting with `eth` (or as a more practical example this also worked to match `virbr+` and `veth+`, i.e. the `+` seemed to have the effect of a `*` in shell globs).

Does nftables offer a similar facility to match interface names? How do I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the usual wildcard character `*` is *nft*'s equivalent of *iptables*' `+`. The man page was not documenting this (relatively old) feature until recently.

From a recent enough [`nft` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/nftables/nft.8#META_EXPRESSIONS):

> Like with iptables, wildcard matching on interface name prefixes is
> available for `iifname` and `oifname` matches by appending an asterisk (*)
> character. Note however that unlike iptables, nftables does not accept
> interface names consisting of the wildcard character only - users are
> supposed to just skip those always matching expressions. In order to
> match on literal asterisk character, one may escape it using backslash
> (\).

eg:

```
iifname "veth*" accept
```

<s>Also, it doesn't appear possible today to use a set of interfaces (`type ifname` or `typeof iifname`) with a wildcard in an element.</s>

UPDATE: this [2022-04 git commit in *nftables*](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=2fb4d7ead460ec4fb00bd317d93a5e076f825b39) along a few other related commits, possibly along adequate kernel support, finally allows to use interface wildcards in sets, using intervals as method:

> Allows to interface names in interval sets:
>
> ```
> table inet filter {
>         set s {
>                 type ifname
>                 flags interval
>                 elements = { eth*, foo }
>         }
> ```

This should become available in the release following current 1.0.2.

---

A completely different method to manage interfaces dynamically appearing and disappearing, would be to tag them with a *group* just after they are created (and probably before they are brought up) and have *nftables* rules matching an interface's group. eg:

```
ip link set ppp7 group 42
```

while having an *nftables* rule reusing this meta information:

```
iifgroup 42 jump from-ppp
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, sets were my plan B in case there was no wildcard option.